# How to use 'CapitalizedString' with Turkish letters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, capitalize, turkish

I have a problem with Turkish letters.

I have a method for deserialize the JSON. I'm getting the correct data from web service and I set it to my object's variable. newsCategory.name contains **'ASKERİ HAVACILIK'** which is NSString.

```
 +(NewsCategory*) convertCategory: (NSMutableDictionary *) jsonDictionary{
        NewsCategory *newsCategory = [[NewsCategory alloc] init];
        newsCategory.name =[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        return newsCategory;
    }
```

I have to convert **'ASKERİ HAVACILIK'** to **'Askeri Havacılık'**. So I used `capitalizedString` for this.

```
NSString *capitalizedName = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
newsCategory.name =  [capitalizedName capitalizedString];
```

But unfortunately, it shows @"Askeri̇ Havacilik"[image]

How I convert this to **'Askeri Havacılık'** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *capitalizedName = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

NSString *accentedString = capitalizedName;
NSString * capitalizedString = [accentedString stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
newsCategory.name =  [capitalizedString capitalizedString];
```

Depending on the nature of the strings you want to convert, you might want to set a fixed locale (e.g. English) instead of using the user's current locale. That way, you can be sure to get the same results on every machine.

Comment: It still shows like 'Askeri Havacilik'. How I convert 'i' to 'ı'? @Melih